# How to create style for hover using CSS so that it can be displayed in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

The system I'm working with dispatches an email information to the customers and alerts them about potential issues. The email contains links to URLs with detailed information on the correct procedure to remedy the problems.

I'd like to improve the experience for the users by making the contents of the rendered message styled with *hover* CSS. It seems not to be supported straight-off in many email clients, though.

As [this link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) specifies, *hover* isn't supported in many version of Outlook, which is a fairly common email client among our customers.

When I process the HTML produced by my software in a browser, it behaves precisely as expected (the style changes the color of a background upon the rat entry over the component). However, the very same HTML rendered in Outlook, doesn't exhibit any reaction.

Is there a work-around? I'm out of ideas and goolearching gave nothing useful.